# Solutions for Dash app timing out on heroku

Tags: heroku, plotly-dash

I have been attempting to create a Dash app as a companion to a report, which I have deployed to heroku:

https://ftacv-simulation.herokuapp.com/

This works reasonably well, for the simplest form of the simulation. However, upon the introduction of more complex features, the heroku server often times out (i.e. a single callback goes over the 30 second limit, and the process is terminated). The two main features are the introduction of a more complex simulation, which requires 15-20 simple simulation runs, and the saving of older plots for the purposes of comparison.

I think I have two potential solutions to this. The first is restructuring the code so that the single large task is broken up into multiple callbacks, none of which go over the 30s limit, and potentially storing the data for the older plots in the user's browser. The second is moving to a different provider that can handle more intense computation (such as AWS).

Which of these approaches would you recommend? Or would you propose a different solution?

Comment: Does [this link](https://community.plotly.com/t/boilerplate-heroku-dash-app-for-long-processes-show-and-tell/8683) help you?

Comment: Have you considered using a worker process for the calculation? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing#use-cases